# Difference Between Rows in Groups with Custom First Row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to get the change in a particular data-frame column within a group.  ".diff()" gets me close, but I need something special for the first row, where it should equal the 'first' value.  I'm trying to get the "Delta" column.  Grouping by "Item", calculating "Delta" as the difference in PrEFPx.

Example:

```
Item   |  Month   |   PrEFPx   |  Delta
-----------------------------------------
 1     |    1     |    1000    |  1000
 1     |    2     |    1000    |  0
 1     |    3     |    1000    |  0
 1     |    4     |    1500    |  500
 1     |    5     |    1500    |  0
 1     |    6     |    1500    |  0
 1     |    7     |    3000    |  1500
 2     |    1     |    5000    |  5000
 2     |    2     |    5000    |  0
 2     |    3     |    5000    |  0
 2     |    4     |    5000    |  0
 2     |    5     |    5000    |  0
 2     |    6     |    4000    |  -1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like just a `groupby().diff` as you mentioned followed by a `fillna`:

```
df['Delta'] = df.groupby('Item')['PrEFPx'].diff().fillna(df['PrEFPx'])
```

Output:

```
    Item  Month  PrEFPx   Delta
0      1      1    1000  1000.0
1      1      2    1000     0.0
2      1      3    1000     0.0
3      1      4    1500   500.0
4      1      5    1500     0.0
5      1      6    1500     0.0
6      1      7    3000  1500.0
7      2      1    5000  5000.0
8      2      2    5000     0.0
9      2      3    5000     0.0
10     2      4    5000     0.0
11     2      5    5000     0.0
12     2      6    4000 -1000.0
```

Or another, yet similar approach with `groupby().shift()`:

```
df['Delta'] = df['PrEFPx'] - df.groupby('Item')['PrEFPx'].shift(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
    Item  Month  PrEFPx  Delta
0      1      1    1000   1000
1      1      2    1000      0
2      1      3    1000      0
3      1      4    1500    500
4      1      5    1500      0
5      1      6    1500      0
6      1      7    3000   1500
7      2      1    5000   5000
8      2      2    5000      0
9      2      3    5000      0
10     2      4    5000      0
11     2      5    5000      0
12     2      6    4000  -1000
```